# Is there a way to find javascript-library dependency trough your application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, updating

In the application I have there are some Javascript-libraries that need to be updated. But with updates there are always parts of the application that break.

It's a APS.NET application and the library that needs to be updated is jQuery-UI

Is there a way to find out where functions are used trougout the application?

Comment: Unless your JS app is built with dependency management from the scratch (bower / requirejs) then the answer is - no, you can't easily track a library throughout your application. You can attempt brute-force regexing but I'm not sure if that's viable at all.

Comment: regretfully that was not build in so I just updating and checking everything seems to be the only thing to do. I hoped there was some tool out there that could find every usage of functions for me.